# Moodle can not work properly load javascript after install via Softaculous

Tags: javascript, installation, moodle

I'm finished install moodle version 3.7.2 via cpanel using Softaculous. I got a problem that after installation moodle just show like this
[image]

moodeldata dir already 0777.

`./
./moodledata
.
.
/public_html/moodle307`

I think it because cannot load cached javascript. Please help.. thank you all

Comment: What does your configuration looks like?

Comment: HI @BlackNetworkBit here I used default config.php, then add theme https://imgur.com/qKMmMQ3

Comment: Does your wwwroot match your real moodle instance location ?

Comment: yes.. wwwroot pointing to my website, I used a subdomain and the location under public_html/elearning [I just edited in the image]

Comment: also trying with uncomment this 
`//@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
//@ini_set('display_errors', '1');    // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
//$CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT);   // === DEBUG_DEVELOPER - NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!
//$CFG->debugdisplay = 1;             // NOT FOR PRODUCTION SERVERS!` still no change

Comment: So your wwwroot is http://elearning.domain.com or http://yoursub.domain.com/elearning ?

Comment: $CFG->wwwroot   = 'https://elearning.myweb.com';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200960/discussion-between-blacknetworkbit-and-enhaka).